# php mailer could not send email

Tags: php, email

I am trying to send an email from localhost with PHP. Here is my code:

```
<?php

// $email and $message are the data that is being
// posted to this page from our html contact form
$email = $_REQUEST['email'] ;
$message = $_REQUEST['message'] ;

require_once('class.phpmailer.php');
require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';
require 'class.smtp.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer();

$mail->IsSMTP();

$mail->Host = "localhost";  // specify main and backup server

$mail->SMTPAuth = false;     // turn on SMTP authentication

$mail->Username = "TTTTTT@gmail.com";  // SMTP username
$mail->Password = ""; // SMTP password
$mail->Port = 25;   
$mail->SMTPSecure = '';  

$mail->From = $email;

$mail->AddAddress("bradm@inmotiontesting.com", "Brad Markle");

$mail->WordWrap = 50;

$mail->IsHTML(true);

$mail->Subject = "You have received feedback from your website!";

$mail->Body    = $message;
$mail->AltBody = $message;

if(!$mail->Send())
{
   echo "Message could not be sent. <p>";
   echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
   exit;
}

echo "Message has been sent";
?>
```

When I run this code, it shows, "message has been sent" but it does not actually send the message. What is my problem?

Comment: If you are using GMAIL to send mail you should check the parameters to connect. You should use SSL to connect to SMTP.

Comment: If really not required then try removing and send one email with simple PHP mail function. If that works then there is problem with Gmail SMTP connection

Answer (score 1):

change this code you have:

```
$mail->Username = "TTTTTT@gmail.com";  // SMTP username
$mail->Password = ""; // SMTP password
$mail->Port = 25;   
$mail->SMTPSecure = '';
```

to this:

```
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  // enable SMTP authentication

$mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";                 // sets the prefix to the servier

$mail->Host       = "smtp.gmail.com";      // sets GMAIL as the SMTP server

$mail->Port       = 587;                   // set the SMTP port for the GMAIL server

$mail->Username   = "yourusername@gmail.com";  // GMAIL username

$mail->Password   = "yourpassword";            // GMAIL password
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what  Lelio Faieta posted, [enable less secure apps in gmail](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en)

and to prevent your mail going to your spam
change

```
$mail->From = $email;
```

to your email and you can put $email in body of your message